# What is ubuntu-mate-vg and how to remove the traces of the Ubuntu Mate desktop?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 17.10, lvm, mate

I am currently using Kubuntu 17.10 but previously I was running the Ubuntu Mate Desktop.

After installing the Kubuntu Desktop, I deleted all the traces of Ubuntu Mate using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mate-desktop
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mate-desktop
sudo apt-get remove mate-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

However, when I opened my KDE partition manager, I saw the following:

[image: First Screenshot]

- **ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA1 - 931.51 GiB (/dev/sda)** - This is where my Kubuntu is installed.
- **ATA Hitachi HDS72101 - 931.51 GiB (/dev/sdb)** - An empty hard drive.
- **ububutu-mate-vg - 931.27 GiB (/dev/ubuntu-mate-vg)** - I have no idea what this is but it seems it is including the ext4 and linuxswamp partitions which logically should belong to the ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA1 (/dev/sda).

**Note:** I have never manually partitioned my hard drive in any way. I always use the default settings and options.

[image: Second Screenshot]

**My Questions:**

Q1). What is the "**ubuntu-mate-vg**" entry that occupies the **/dev/sda5** in the same device of my Kubuntu installation (First Screenshot)?

Q2). What is that "**ubuntu-mate-vg**" entry that is taking a whole section in my list of devices (Second Screenshot)? and is it possible to delete it?

Any comments, suggestions, or answers will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance for reading my questions.

Comment: "ububutu-mate-vq - 931.27 GiB (/dev/ubuntu-mate-vq)" may just be `vg` if you look carefully.

Comment: Thank you! I had a typing mistake on here. I still don't know what vg is.

Comment: My general advice about testing desktop environments 'DEs': If you want to try another DE, try it in a separate operating system, not in your main production system. The reason is that it is very difficult to get rid of everything from the tested DE without causing damage to the original DE. -- If you did already test a DE in your main production system, it might be better to keep it there alongside the original DE and select the DE you want to use at the log in screen.

Comment: `ubuntu-mate-vg` is likely just the default volume group name chosen by the installer when you selected the *"Use the entire disk and setup LVM"* partitioning option - see for example [Advanced Installation: Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#lvm) -it doesn't mean there's any "trace" of the mate desktop (beyond the name).

Comment: @steeldriver : +1 Thank you very much for clarifying that. I greatly appreciate your comment. I thought it was something related to Ubuntu Mate.